# How do I edit the two labels of one input field separately?

Tags: html, css, input, label

[this is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPICp.png)How do you edit two labels for the same input field in CSS separately? I want to have a label above an input field that says "Nickname" and then a lower label that says "(press enter to spawn)" but I don't know how to position them like that and I also don't know how to change the size so that I can make the bottom one smaller. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you give us your code, we will be able to help you after.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> Test Page </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css" media="screen" -->
<style>
 .wrapper { width: 20em; }
</style>
</head><body>
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div> Nickname: </div>
 <input type="text" id="nickname" placeholder='Nickname'>
 <div> (press enter to spawn) </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I've already solved this problem but thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: What did your solution look like?

Comment: I just added it into some <span> tags but I've scraped that website and completely redid it.